# Creating a fixed size array of type class with 2 parameters?

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently in a beginner level class here at Louisiana Tech University and I'm needing help with how I'm supposed to do a specific part of this assignment that is getting me stuck. I am trying to code a fixed size array that models a deck of playing cards, and I've made it through most of the assignment.

I've reached a portion of the assignment that asks to make a fixed size array of type Class and assign it to deck, which I've done. It then asks to use for loops to initialize and create each card in a deck. I created the for loops successfully, but when I inspect the Card[] deck object, it shows null instead of the card that were supposed to be initialized.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atKst.png) of my 2 classes, and how it has asked me to set the code up so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please follow the rules for the site and edit your code into the question. Links become unavailable making questions useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the local variable "deck" instead of the instance variable.

Use

```
this.deck = new Card[52];
```

before the loop, instead of

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52];
```

and then in the loop:

```
this.deck[position] = new Card(....);
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely overlooked that Card[] also created a new variable like regular types, instead of assigning it to the instance variable. Now let's see if I can get the rest of this assignment without anymore problems, haha.

Comment: No problem, since that helped please accept the answer.